# C# Winforms Crystal Report Viewer in new form

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a form where I get some data from textboxes into hard typed DataSet myDataSet. I have created a typed Crystal Report myReport. When I click on the button I want to open new form and load report into Crystal Report Viewer myViewer. Here I have a problem. I do not know how to get data into myViewer.

Here is what I tried:

```
myDataSet ds = new myDataSet();
getData(out ds);
myReportForm viewForm = new myReportForm();
viewForm.Owner = this;

myReport report = new myReport();
report.SetDataSource(ds);

//How do I get this report into new form which has Report Viewer??
//I thought it would be something like (doesnt work):
//
//viewForm.myViewer.ReportSource = ds;

viewForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to show a report in a new form using the Crystal Report viewer, using a form variable to set the report variable:

```
ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();                
string reportPath = Path.Combine(REPORT_PATH, "myReport.rpt");
myReport.Load(reportPath);                
DataTable dt = myTableAdapter.GetDataByID(txtID.Text);
myReport.SetDataSource(dt.DefaultView);
myReport.SetParameterValue("ID", txtID.Text);
frmReportViewer frm = new frmReportViewer(myReport);
frm.Show();
```

The GetDataByID is a custom query added using the designer. The report passed into the frmReportViewer is passed to the ReportSource of the CrystalReport viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following Steps

1.Create a new `Form` with name `myReportForm` add `crystalReportViewer` form the toolbox

2.Open your Debug folder and add a new folder with name Reports, copy your reports inside the folder

3.Make sure to add `using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;`

```
try
 {

  Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
  ReportDocument myReport = new ReportDocument();
  string reportPath = (Application.StartupPath + @"ReportPath");
  var ds = new DataSet();
  String SqlQuery = "Query";
  var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, connectionString);
  adapter.Fill(ds, "Table or View Name");
  myReport.Load(reportPath);
  myReport.SetDataSource(ds);
  var frm = new myReportForm();
  frm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReport;
  frm.Show();

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myReport` is of type `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocuemnt`  you need to set the `ReportSource` to the report.

```
viewForm.myViewer.ReportSource = myReport;
```

Based on your example too, you need to make sure that the `CrystalReportViewer` on the form is `public` or you wont be able to access it's properties from outside the class.

One additional note, you should follow .Net naming conventions for your class names

`myReportForm` should be `MyReportForm` etc...